# Attempting to create V8ScriptEngine instance fails with IExpando error

Tags: c#, clearscript

I am trying to create an instance of V8ScriptEngine but am getting an exception as below:

```
using Microsoft.ClearScript.V8;
V8ScriptEngine engine = new V8ScriptEngine();
```

Exception: `"Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Expando.IExpando' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."`

What am I missing? This is ClearScript version 5.4

Comment: are you on .net Core?

Comment: @vasily.sib yes it is

Comment: as [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.expando.iexpando?view=netframework-4.8#moniker-applies-to) states - it's not supported on .net Core

Comment: but as [github](https://github.com/microsoft/clearscript) states - it is supported in .net Core 3.1 but only on Windows

Comment: @vasily.sib righto, my project is using .net core 3.0. Am currently having a go at updating it to use 3.1. Will let you know how that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET Core support, you need ClearScript 6.0 (or higher).